# how to add .c, .cc and .so file in makefile to create another .so?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, makefile, gnu-make

I want to use *C++* Library in *C* that's why I wrote a wrapper for *C* which contains a **wr.h**, **wr.cc**, and a test program **test.c**. So, I wrote a makefile (given below) to create a **.so** file for my wrapper. But It shows undefined reference to the library. Any suggestion?

```
PROGRAM = MYWR

INCLUDEDIRS = -I/path/to/include
LIBDIRS = -L/path/to/lib/

LIBS = -labc -lbcd

CXXSOURCES = wr.cc
CSOURCES = test.c
CXXOBJECTS = $(CXXSOURCES:.cc=.o)
COBJECTS = $(CSOURCES:.c=.o)

CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=gnu++11 $(INCLUDEDIRS)
CXX = g++

LDFLAGS = $(LIBDIRS) $(LIBS)

all: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): $(CXXOBJECTS) $(COBJECTS)
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(CXXOBJECTS) $(COBJECTS)
```

Any Suggestion???

Answer (score 1):

Move the `-lxxx` to the end of the command line? Sometimes the order does matter:

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(CXXOBJECTS) $(COBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: thanks it works. What lines do I need to add to make .so file then? it creates the only executable file.

Comment: It should be `$(CXX) -shared -o $@ ...` but I'm pretty sure that on most platforms it **DOES NOT** include the .so code in your new .so. I.e. you'll still need the other .so to be available to run your C code.

Comment: But it shows relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC. any guess why?

Comment: All code that goes into dynamic library needs to be location independent. Did you make sure to have `CXXFLAGS = -fPIC` **and** `CFLAGS = -fPIC`? As your makefile doesn't define rules for .cpp/.c -> .o the default ones are going to be used. That means test.c is compiled with `$(CC) $(CFLAGS)`. Probably your .cpp code too, which means it may not see `$(CXXFLAGS)` also.

Comment: Based on my experience I would suggest to add explicit rules for .o generation and not rely on the default ones. E.g. 

`$(COBJECTS): *.o: *.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<`

Comment: If I want to use my shared library with Postgres backend suppose from copy.c. how can I do this? @Stefan Becker

Comment: Assuming that your build artifact `mywr.so` is located under `libs` the command line to link a program against it should be `$(CC) -o copy -c copy.c -Llibs -lmywr`. Please note that you add the `-l` to the *final* link command and not to the compilation commands.